# Tables with SXA

Tags: sxa

We have a requirement to create simple tables using Sitecore SXA 1.7.1.

I could think of 2 options:

1. Richtext field where content editors insert table without any styling. Why not - Error prone. Not limiting fantasy of content editors :-) which could end with inconsistency of tables look & feel on different pages
2. Using row and column splitters. Why not - Too fluid and not behaving as html table.

Do you create separate table component? How would you solve table component with SXA?

Comment: I would go with the rich text one as a developer. as a Content editor I will got for the rows and columns.

Comment: A requirement to implement "simple tables" screams loudly to the sky; "RTE"